# Python unittest: Retry on failure with Nose?

Tags: python, nose

I have a test which randomly fails and I want to let it retry a number of times before sending an error message.

I'm using python with Nose.

I wrote the following, but unfortunately, even with the try/except handling, Nose returns an error when the test fails on the first try.

```
def test_something(self):
    maxAttempts = 3
    func = self.run_something

    attempt = 1
    while True:
        if attempt == maxAttempts:
            yield func
            break

        else:
            try:
                yield func
                break
            except:
                attempt += 1

def run_something(self):
    #Do stuff
```

Thanks

Comment: If it fails only sometimes, that's a reason to treat it as a particular nasty bug, not to mask it.

Comment: In my case, it is acceptable that it is often failing (it depends on external resources, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using a generator, you're giving nose `maxAttempts` tests to run.  if *any* of them fail, the suite fails.  The try/catch doesn't particularly apply to the tests your yielding, since its nose that runs them.  Rewrite your test like so:

```
def test_something(self):
    maxAttempts = 3
    func = self.run_something

    attempt = 1
    while True:
        if attempt == maxAttempts:
            func() # <<<--------
            break

        else:
            try:
                func() # <<<--------
                break
            except:
                attempt += 1

def run_something(self):
    #Do stuff
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried using generators for cleaner handling of setup and teardown, but this works just as well

Answer (score 4):

You can use attributes on your functions with the [flaky nose plugin](https://github.com/box/flaky) that will automatically re-run tests and let you use advanced parameters (like if 2 in 3 test pass, then it's a pass)

[GitHub flaky project](https://github.com/box/flaky)

How to install Flaky plugin for Python:

```
pip install flaky
```

Example nose test runner configuration:

```
nosetests.exe your_python_tests.py --with-flaky --force-flaky --max-runs=3
```

Example Python code with function marked with Flaky attribute:

```py
from flaky import flaky

@flaky
def test_something_that_usually_passes(self):
    value_to_double = 21
    result = get_result_from_flaky_doubler(value_to_double)
    self.assertEqual(result, value_to_double * 2, 'Result doubled incorrectly.')
```